# Expect: extract specific string from output

Tags: tcl, expect

I am navigating a Java-based CLI menu on a remote machine with expect inside a bash script and I am trying to extract something from the output without leaving the expect session.

Expect command in my script is:

```
expect -c "
spawn ssh user@host
expect \"#\"
send \"java cli menu command here\r\"
expect \"java cli prompt\"
send \"java menu command\"
"
###I want to extract a specific string from the above output###
```

Expect output is:

```
Id       Name
-------------------
abcd 12  John Smith
```

I want to extract `abcd 12` from the above output into another expect variable for further use within the expect script. So that's the 3rd line, first field by using a double-space delimiter. The awk equivalent would be: `awk -F '  ' 'NR==3 {$1}'`

The big issue is that the environment through which I am navigating with Expect is, as I stated above, a Java CLI based menu so I can't just use awk or anything else that would be available from a bash shell.

Getting out from the Java menu, processing the output and then getting in again is not an option as the login process lasts for 15 seconds so I need to remain inside and extract what I need from the output using expect internal commands only.

Comment: The core of the problem is that you're trying to put the expect script into a double-quoted shell literal. That's going to force you to use _lots_ of backslash quoting. While you can do things that way, putting the expect script in its own file (e.g., `mydostuff.exp`) makes everything so much simpler. Then you can run it with `expect mydostuff.exp`…

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `regexp` in `expect` itself directly with the use of `-re` flag. Thanks to Donal on pointing out the single quote and double quote issues. I have given solution using both ways.

I have created a file with the content as follows,

```
Id       Name
-------------------
abcd 12  John Smith
```

This is nothing but your java program's console output. I have tested this in my system with this. i.e. I just simulated your program's output with `cat`. You just replace the `cat` code with your program commands. Simple. :)

**Double Quotes :**

```
#!/bin/bash
expect -c "
spawn ssh user@domain
expect \"password\"
send \"mypassword\r\"
expect {\\\$} { puts matched_literal_dollar_sign}
send \"cat input_file\r\"; # Replace this code with your java program commands
expect -re {-\r\n(.*?)\s\s}
set output \$expect_out(1,string)
#puts \$expect_out(1,string)
puts \"Result : \$output\"
"
```

**Single Quotes :**

```
#!/bin/bash
expect -c '
spawn ssh user@domain
expect "password"
send "mypasswordhere\r"
expect "\\\$" { puts matched_literal_dollar_sign}
send "cat input_file\r"; # Replace this code with your java program commands
expect -re {-\r\n(.*?)\s\s}
set output $expect_out(1,string)
#puts $expect_out(1,string)
puts "Result : $output"
'
```

As you can see, I have used `{-\r\n(.*?)\s\s}`. Here the braces prevent any variable substitutions. In your output, we have a 2nd line with full of hyphens. Then a newline. Then your 3rd line content. Let's decode the regex used.

`-\r\n` is to match one literal hyphen and a new line together. This will match the last hyphen in the 2nd line and the newline which in turn make it to 3rd line now. So, `.*?` will match the required output (i.e. abcd 12) till it encounters double space which is matched by `\s\s`.

You might be wondering why I need parenthesis which is used to get the sub-match patterns.

In general, `expect` will save the expect's whole match string in `expect_out(0,string)` and buffer all the matched/unmatched input to `expect_out(buffer)`. Each sub match will be saved in subsequent numbering of string such as `expect_out(1,string)`, `expect_out(2,string)` and so on.

[image]

As Donal pointed out, it is better to use single quote's approach since it looks less messy. :)

It is not required to escape the `\r` with the backslash in case of double quotes.

**Update :**

I have changed the `regexp` from `-\r\n(\w+\s+\w+)\s\s` to `-\r\n(.*?)\s\s`.

With this way - your requirement - such as `match any number of letters and single spaces until you encounter first occurrence of double spaces in the output`

Now, let's come to your question. You have mentioned that you have tried `-\r\n(\w+)\s\s`. But, there is a problem here with `\w+`. Remember `\w+` will not match space character.  Your output has some spaces in it till double spaces.

The use of regexp will matter based on your requirements on the input string which is going to get matched. You can customize the regular expressions based on your needs.

**Update version 2 :**

What is the significance of `.*?`.  If you ask separately, I am going to repeat what you commented. In regular expressions, `*` is a greedy operator and `?` is our life saver. Let us consider the string as

```
Stackoverflow is already overflowing with number of users.
```

Now, see the effect of the regular expression `.*flow` as below.

[image]

`*` matches any number of characters. **More precisely, it matches the longest string possible while still allowing the pattern itself to match.**  So, due to this, `.*` in the pattern matched the characters  `Stackoverflow is already over` and `flow` in pattern matched the text `flow` in the string.

Now, in order to prevent the `.*` to match only up to the first occurrence of the string `flow`, we are adding the `?` to it. It will help the pattern to behave as non-greedy manner.

[image]

Now, again coming back to your question. If we have used `.*\s\s`, then it will match the whole line since it is trying to match as much as possible. This is common behavior of regular expressions.

**Update version 3:**

Have your code in the following way.

```
x=$(expect -c "
spawn ssh user@host
expect \"password\"
send \"password\r\"
expect {\\\$} { puts matched_literal_dollar_sign}
send \"cat input\r\"
expect -re {-\r\n(.*?)\s\s}
if {![info exists expect_out(1,string)]} {
        puts \"Match did not happen :(\"
        exit 1
}
set output \$expect_out(1,string)
#puts \$expect_out(1,string)
puts \"Result : \$output\"
")
y=$?

# $x now contains the output from the 'expect' command, and $y contains the
# exit status
echo $x
echo $y;
```

If the flow happened properly, then exit code will have value as 0. Else, it will have 1. With this way, you can check the return value in bash script.

Have a look at [here](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl27.html) to know about the `info exists` command.

Comment: You need to backslash-quote the `$` or the unix shell will mangle it; using `expect -c "…"` just adds whole layers of annoying mess to everything. The `\r`s might also need an extra backslash.

Comment: @linux_newbie : I have updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: @DonalFellows : Thank you so much Donal for helping me out to learn more about this. I have corrected as well as tested my answer. Let me know for any other changes.

Comment: Thank you both, I just tried it and it works. But the output of my Java command is variable, sometimes instead of `abcd 12` I could just have `abc` or `abc def ghi` or `abc def ghi jkl`. I am trying to use a regex that basically says "match any number of letters and single spaces until you encounter double spaces" but I didn't manage to make it work. If you have any suggestion I would appreciate it.

Comment: I don't understand why the below regex doesn't work to match any number of "words": `-\r\n(\w+)\s\s`. Doesn't `\w+` mean "match at least once"? From tcl man, a word is defined by: `[[:alnum:]_]` In fact, my regex doesn't match anything, not even when the result is a single word.

Comment: @Dinesh : Thank you very much for your help, the suggested regex `.*?` worked. Inspired by this, I also tried `.+` and it also worked with a result containing four words. Now what I don't fully understand is the explanation for `\w+` not working as intended. I already knew it would not match spaces, in fact I was counting on the fact the the single spaces would represent the word "delimiters" and since I specified "match one or more" with `+`, I was expecting this to work just like your suggested regex or mine did in the end.

Comment: Ah, I was too late in editing my previous post. I found that without the `?`, the whole line is matched. I read your regex like this: `.` = match any character; `*` = 0 or more times; `?` = optional, match 0 or 1 time. I don't understand how the `?` operates in this case, in normal (non-tcl) regex usage I just use either `*` or `?`

Comment: @linux_newbie : I have updated my answer again. Please check.

Comment: @Dinesh : Thank you very much for taking the time to explain. I was a bit thrown off by the fact that there was no grouping used like: `(.*)?`. Somehow this kind of representation makes more sense to me. I appreciate the help, again thank you.

Comment: I think this warranted another question on stackoverflow but it's somewhat related to this question. Sometimes, because the user input is incorrect, the `-re` will not match anything so the `expect_out(1,string)` will be empty. This generates an internal expect error: `can't read "expect_out(1,string)": no such element in array` which is fine. But I did this in my shell script: `variable=$(expect -c 'expect commands')` so I was expecting the expect error to be put into the shell's variable content but this does not happen so I cannot perform simple `if` conditions depending on variable content

Comment: @linux_newbie : I have updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: @Dinesh : Thanks for the reply. I tried `if { [info exists $expect_out(1,string)] }` and I get this error: `can't read "expect_out(1,string)": no such element in array
    while executing
"info exists $expect_out(1,string)"` -> this is exactly what I wanted to avoid. Is there a way to prevent this kind of expect internal errors to be displayed?

Comment: @Dinesh : I also tried with `$?` and it returns 0 when expect is generating the error. But I am primarily interested to suppress the error message of expect. I will try to do a stderr redirect to /dev/null.

Comment: @Dinesh : tried `expect -c 'commands' 2>/dev/null`, I still get that error displayed.

Comment: @linux_newbie : I am surprised. When I have tried this, it was working fine. Wondering what is different from your side.

Comment: @Dinesh : which method worked for you? Maybe I can insist on it and see why it is not working for me as it should. When you tried, did you create the conditions to generate the `no such element in array` error? And did you manage to supress this output?

Comment: @linux_newbie : In the above comments, you have mentioned like you have tried `if { [info exists $expect_out(1,string)] }`. That is not correct. You should use `if { [info exists expect_out(1,string)] }`. There should not be a `$` sign. After this it will work for sure. Please try and update.

Comment: @Dinesh : Thank you very much for your time and patience, it works now. I actually saw in your link that the reference to variables while using `info exists` did not contain a `$` in front but since I've been referencing all my expect variable with `$` in front I thought this was the correct way to do it so I did not even think to try without `$`.