# Erratic behaviour of expect shell when passing arguments to shell script

Tags: bash, expect

This piece of code works fine without command line parameters but stops after login into the linux box when i am passing the IP as a parameter to the script

bash -x -o igncr Master.sh 10.104.24.196

I am clueless what is going on, any help will be appreciated.

```
if [ "$#" -eq 0  ]; then
IP="10.104.24.196"
else
IP="$1"
fi
PWD="something"
echo "Connecting to $IP with password:$PWD"
> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
/usr/bin/expect -<< EOD
set timeout -1
spawn ssh "$IP" -l root
expect "(yes/no)?"
send "yes\n"
expect "password"
    send "$PWD\n" 
    expect "$*" <- stops here
    send  "cd somewhere\n"
    send "./db_deploy.sh\n"
    expect "Script execution completed."
        send "cd somewhere\n"
        send "./apps_deploy.sh\n"
        expect "Script execution completed."
            send "exit\n"
expect eof
EOD
#dosomething else
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because of `expect "$*"`.

If you want to match the literal dollar sign (`$`), then you should use the following way when used inside double quotes.

```
expect {\\\$}
```

Since `$` sign is special to both `tcl` and `expect`, in order to match the literal dollar sign, we need to escape it with backslash twice and of course one more backslash to escape the backslash itself.

There are 2 more enhancements which can be done are as follows,

To send 'enter/return' key via `expect`, we are advised to use `\r`, not `\n`.  (Though it is not big deal in your question. :))

Before spawning ssh session , you are overwriting the `known_hosts` file (`> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`) and thereby you are expecting for '(yes/no)' which happen only when the host is new to the system.

```
spawn ssh "$IP" -l root
expect "(yes/no)?
```

With the help of `exp_continue`, we can handle the same without overwriting the known_hosts. (But, if deleting the known hosts each time is your real intention, you do not need to add this part)

By combining these changes in your script, it will be like as follows,

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$#" -eq 0  ]; then
IP="10.104.24.196"
else
IP="$1"
fi
PWD="something"
echo "Connecting to $IP with password:$PWD" 
# I have commented this line, since I am using exp_continue.
# If you don't want, then keep your code as such
#> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
/usr/bin/expect -<< EOD
set timeout 60; # 1 min of timeout 
spawn ssh "$IP" -l root
expect { 
        # you can keep your old code here if you want.
        "(yes/no)" {send "yes\r";exp_continue}
        "password" 
}
send "$PWD\r" 
expect {\\\$}
send  "cd somewhere\r"
send "./db_deploy.sh\r"
expect "Script execution completed."
send "cd somewhere\r"
send "./apps_deploy.sh\r"
expect "Script execution completed."
send "exit\r"
expect eof
EOD
```

Instead of embedding expect script directly into the bash script, you can keep the file separately and call the expect script like as follows,

```
expect -c yourscript.exp
```

Have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27089739/expect-extract-specific-string-from-output/) to know about usage of double quotes and single quotes while embedding the expect script in a bash script.

**Update :** How poor I'm to miss the `timeout` value.

`expect`'s default timeout value is 10 seconds. This can be changed by setting a new value.

```
set timeout 60; # This value is in terms of seconds.
```

**By setting timeout to -1, we are making it to wait for infinitely.**  You have used that value. Try changing that to some other value (like 60 which is 1 min).

Perhaps, in your case, if `$` didn't get matched, it will proceed as such. If you want to handle the `timeout` gracefully, you should have use the following.

```
expect {
         {\\\$} {puts "matched dollar sign"}
         timeout { puts "timeout happened"}
}
```

Still this does not answer your question precisely. Can you try the `expect` with `-d` flag and share the output in your question ? So that we can help you.

Comment: with expect {\\\$} it is stopping there always with or without the command line parameters !

Comment: And i didnt understand how passing an argument was affecting the expect shell . My code works when no argument is passed.

Comment: @raynaya :  Oops. My bad. Just now found the prob. See the updated answer. :)

Comment: thanks. That will solve the problem of it getting stuck but still the output of the shell should be same with or without command line parameters, so not able to understand why it is getting stuck when i am passing parameter. I will check with -d flag. Actually i need -1 timeout value as some of the activities will take a lot of  time.

Comment: @raynaya:  I have tested this code with/without command line argument and it is working fine. Awaiting for the debug information from your side.

Comment: I found the problem. Your first assumption was correct when i was doing a expect "$*", $* was getting replaced by my first command line arguemnt. And when there was no parameter it was resolving $* to " " which matches with the output. Your solution should have worked but the problem was the machine i was running on didnt give a $ for prompt. Thanks !

Comment: @raynaya : Great! Glad to know. :)

Comment: one QQ will the exp_continue work if timeout is set to -1 . Is there a way to override that ?

Comment: By default, `exp_continue` resets the `timeout` timer. The timer is not restarted, if `exp_continue` is called with the `-continue_timer` flag. Other than this, `exp_continue` does not have any impact other than making the `expect` to loop it one more time.