# gitlab automated pushing script

Tags: bash, automation, push, expect

Im trying to write a script which is automatically pushing to my server as soon as i change a file.

My current result is this:

```
#! /bin/bash
DIRECTORY_TO_OBSERVE="/home/test"
function block_for_change {
  inotifywait -r \
    -e 'modify,move,create,delete' --exclude '(/4913|.swx|.swp)$' \
    $DIRECTORY_TO_OBSERVE
}

while block_for_change; do
git add --all
git rm $(git ls-files --deleted)
git commit -m 'Update -  $(date)'
git push -u origin master
expect "Username:"
send "TestUsernme\r\n"
expect "Password:"
send "TestPassword\r\n"
done
```

However, the expect is not working as it should. An example log is this:
Watches established.

```
/home/test/ MOVED_FROM test.sh
[master 8a749f5] Update -  $(date)
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
Username for 'http://git.':
```

What is wrong in my script? Why it isnt detected that the username and password is expected?

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to use the `expect` code inside a bash script, then better keep the code within `expect -c` flag.

```
git add --all
git rm $(git ls-files --deleted)
git commit -m 'Update -  $(date)'
git push -u origin master
# Keeping the 'expect' code with '-c' flag
expect -c "
exp_internal 1; #Remove this line once your prob solved
expect \"Username:\"
send \"TestUsernme\r\n\"
expect \"Password:\"
send \"TestPassword\r\n\"
"
```

Note that I have escaped the double quotes with backslash. Have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27090684/974155) to know about the significance of using double quotes and single quotes with the `expect -c` flag

Comment: Is it required that the expect attribute is matching to 100% with the line?
Its actually `Username for 'http://git.mydomain.net':` for the first input.

Comment: Yes. So, better change it to 'Username' alone. You can apply regular expression or glob pattern if you want.

Comment: Well changed it so, but it still doesnt work:

`Watches established.
/home/test/ CREATE test.h
[master 886d790] Update -  $(date)
 2 files changed, 4 insertions(+), 4 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 test.h
Username for 'http://git.mydomain.net':
`
the line is there but there is no username written...

Comment: Then change it to `expect -re \"Username.*?:\"` and see. If still problem seen, then add debug and post your observation. Updated my post about this.